Uniquely generated binary strings
How does one determine whether or not an alphabet uniquely generates each string? For example, the alphabet $\{10,0,01\}$ does not uniquely generate strings since $010=0+10=01+0$. On the other hand, I am certain that $\{00,1,01\}$ uniquely generates each string, but how does one show this?
Here is the proof that we did in class to show that $F=\{000,00001,10\}$ uniquely generates each string:
Let $w$ be any binary string over $F$, and let $k$ denote the number of zeros in the last block of zeros in $w$ (so if $w$ ends with a $1$, then $k=0$).
If $k=3n$ for some $n\geq0$, then either $w=(000)^n$ or $w=w'(00001)(000)^n$ for some string $w'$ over $F$.
If $k=3n+1$, then $w=w'(10)(000)^n$. Lastly, it is not possible that $k=3n+2$.
So in regards to $\{00,1,01\}$, should I also do a proof that involves modular arithmetic, or is there another method? And if we were to try and apply it to $\{10,0,01\}$, where would it fall apart?

You are essentially asking if a set of strings (let's say codewords) is uniquely decodable, i.e., if every possible output string as a unique parsing into a concatenation of strings from the set of codewords.
There is an algorithm that can decide this, called the Sardinas-Patterson algorithm; See Wikipedia. There is also a discussion in this homework assignment.
Sometimes a quick way to decide that a set of strings cannot be uniquely decodable is to check whether the lengths obey the Kraft's inequality. If they don't the code is not prefix-free and thus is not uniquely decodable.
